# What is a Sticky Broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent

I came across this term in the android documentation with the accompanying definition

> These are broadcasts whose data is held by the system after being finished, so that clients can quickly retrieve that data without having to wait for the next broadcast.

What does it mean? Can someone elaborate its use with a particular example? I believe we have to request a permission for using this intent? Why so?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/> - Allows an application to broadcast sticky intents.
```

Comment: 08/Feb/2019, for anyone searching sticky broadcast and ended here, from [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) ```Sticky broadcasts should not be used. They provide no security (anyone can access them), no protection (anyone can modify them), and many other problems. The recommended pattern is to use a non-sticky broadcast to report that something has changed, with another mechanism for apps to retrieve the current value whenever desired.```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If an Activity calls `onPause` with a normal broadcast, receiving the Broadcast can be missed. A sticky broadcast can be checked after it was initiated in `onResume`.

## Update 6/23/2020

**Sticky broadcasts are deprecated.**

[*See `sendStickyBroadcast` documentation*.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent))

> This method was deprecated in API level 21.

> Sticky broadcasts should not be used. They provide no security (anyone can access them), no protection (anyone can modify them), and many other problems. The recommended pattern is to use a non-sticky broadcast to report that something has changed, with another mechanism for apps to retrieve the current value whenever desired.

## Implement

```
Intent intent = new Intent("some.custom.action");
intent.putExtra("some_boolean", true);
sendStickyBroadcast(intent);
```

## Resources

- Related post: [What is the difference between sendStickyBroadcast and sendBroadcast in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21829301/2253682)
- See [`removeStickyBroadcast(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)), and on API Level 5 +,  [`isInitialStickyBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#isInitialStickyBroadcast()) for usage in the Receiver's `onReceive`.

Comment: Hi, I am getting confused with sticky broadcast with the statically registering of the broadcast. I just read somewhere that the difference between registering a broadcast in the manifest file and registering programatically is only that the further one do not unregister the broadcast but it stays there, while the later one unregisters the broadcast in onPause() method.

Comment: Note: in most cases, sticky broadcasts should be avoided. See [the link in the answer from @Nikhil_Katre](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f37e3549a5e1be66?pli=1) for more info

Comment: @Shaista: manifest receivers operate even when your app is dormant whereas a programmatic receiver only responds when the application it is registered within is running

Comment: @gmale So, if we are activity and we are in onPause() and we have called unregisterReceiver().. Will we get the broadcast when we resume in onResume()

Comment: @PaulBurke I didn't find name **Mark Murphy** in the above given link. This Link redirects me to the question not on the exact answer. Can you please update the URL?.

Answer (score 13):

`sendStickyBroadcast()` performs a `sendBroadcast(Intent)` known as sticky, i.e. the Intent you are sending stays around after the broadcast is complete, so that others can quickly retrieve that data through the return value of `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)`. In all other ways, this behaves the same as `sendBroadcast(Intent)`. One example of a sticky broadcast sent via the operating system is `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. When you call `registerReceiver()` for that action -- even with a null `BroadcastReceiver` -- you get the Intent that was last broadcast for that action. Hence, you can use this to find the state of the battery without necessarily registering for all future state changes in the battery.

Answer (score 9):

The value of a sticky broadcast is the value that was last broadcast and is currently held in the sticky cache.  This is not the value of a broadcast that was received right now.  I suppose you can say it is like a browser cookie that you can access at any time.  The sticky broadcast is now deprecated, per the docs for sticky broadcast methods ([e.g.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent))):

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. Sticky broadcasts should
>   not be used. They provide no security (anyone can access them), no
>   protection (anyone can modify them), and many other problems. The
>   recommended pattern is to use a non-sticky broadcast to report that
>   something has changed, with another mechanism for apps to retrieve the
>   current value whenever desired.

Answer (score 3):

A normal broadcast Intent is not available anymore after is was send and processed by the system. If you use the sendStickyBroadcast(Intent) method, the Intent is sticky, meaning the Intent you are sending stays around after the broadcast is complete.

you refer to my blog:[enter link description here](http://aruljack.blogspot.in/2012/10/what-is-meant-by-stick-intents.html)

Comment: I have added the required disclosure of your authorship of the blog you are linking to. You *must* do this yourself from now on, or your posts are subject to being deleted as spam.