# App requires android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY

Tags: android, apache-flex, permissions, flex4

I've recompiled my app with Flex 4.6 / AIR 3.1 and now when I upload to the Android market it says my app is using a "android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" permission. In it's simplest terms what is it and can or should I turn it off (it's not in the app descriptor file)?

BTW I used captive runtime for the first time in this upload. Would that have anything to do with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems AIR 3.4 removes the requirement for this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no way of removing this permission, its required when compiling your apk.

Read Adobe's Android APK packages documentation
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-4f1413de12cd45ccc23-8000.html

It has a note:"When you bundle the runtime, ADT adds the INTERNET and BROADCAST_STICKY permissions to your application. These permissions are required by the AIR runtime."

Comment: This is the correct answer. The only solution would be to create a non-captive apk, but that means users would be prompted to install Adobe AIR upon running your application (if they haven't done so).

Answer (score 1):

As for what is this intent it's described here in another stack overflow post: [What is a Sticky Broadcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490913/what-is-a-sticky-intent-android) As for why it's in there I don't have a clue (I wouldn't imagine that bundling with captivate would cause this problem though I suppose it's worth trying without it).

It seems you can probably open the apk using a compression program and edit AndroidManifest.xml to see if this is having any effect too.

Comment: Thanks - let's hope it's removed in the future.