# What is a permanent broadcast?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a Sticky Intent? [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490913/what-is-a-sticky-intent-android)

I've found that some applications require a special permission to "send permanent broadcasts". I don't know what they are and how can those be helpful.

First, I don't know if I'm talinkg about `public static final String BROADCAST_STICKY`, and second can you *briefly* describe me how these permanent broadcasts work?

Or, obviously, you can address me to the proper documentation

Comment: Most important is that you got your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of: [What is a Sticky Broadcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490913/what-is-a-sticky-intent-android)

Documentation is here; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BROADCAST_STICKY

> Allows an application to broadcast sticky intents. These are
>   broadcasts whose data is held by the system after being finished, so
>   that clients can quickly retrieve that data without having to wait for
>   the next broadcast.