# Are Android Intents buffered up?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, usb

I am trying to catch an Intent from installing a USB device.  That is I want to start a Service.  But, if the Service is started by other means, I would like to take a different course of action.  However, my test to see if the Intent is from installing a USB device is passing even when I think is should not.  For example, I can start the Service from a different Android application.

So I'm wondering.  Can there be a bunch of Intents waiting to be processed?  It would explain why I see my Intent test pass even if I think I didn't do anything to cause it to pass.

I am trying to test for an Intent using Try / Catch code.  I dropped extra code that is not related:

```
try{
     Log.d(TAG, "Checking Intent to see if service started due to Intent");
     extras = getUSBAccessoryIntentExtras(intent);
     Log.d(TAG, "Service started due to Intent");
   }
   catch(NoUSBIntentFoundException nuife){
     Log.d(TAG, "Exception Caught: No intent found error.");
   }
```

Comment: Whats in `getUSBAccessoryIntentExtras`?

Comment: Android has a concept of SticyBroadcast. If intent is sent using sticybroadcast, then it remains cached in system: Follow this link for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490913/what-is-a-sticky-intent-android

Comment: Yes, that was my bad.  I tried to reduce the code just for this question and skipped over that part. It is a method that checks if the intent is 1) null, 2) if the intent's extras are null and 3) if there are certain extras.keySet() values.  In forcing me to say this I realize there is nothing here that can tell the difference between an intent from a USB insertion and one from another program.