# Get battery level before broadcast receiver responds for Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

I have a broadcast receiver in my program to get react to the battery level like so:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        // do something...
    }
}

    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

However this code has to wait for the battery status to be updated so if you have a GUI element that needs to be set based on the battery level it must wait for a battery event to occur. Is there a way to nudge this to get it working or simply run some code to see what the battery level was on the last broadcast?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is there a way to nudge this to get it working or simply run some code to see what the battery level was on
>   the last broadcast?

You can call `registerReceiver()` with your `IntentFilter` and a `null` `BroadcastReceiver` to get the last-broadcast `Intent`. This works because `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a so-called "sticky broadcast", which I describe a bit more in [this StackOverflow question-and-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584497/what-is-the-difference-between-sendstickybroadcast-and-sendbroadcast-in-android).

Comment: The receiver I have in the question actually is called as soon as it is created I just didn't notice because I reinitialised the variables after it.

Comment: Will getting the applicationContext as described below to make this call cause problems?  I have the problem that my broadcast receiver isn't allowed to register for intents, even though I pass in null.  What is the correct solution to this problem?

Comment: @Mayra: `getApplicationContext()` should be fine here, particularly if you are trying to do this from a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 84):

This is how to get the battery level without registering a receiver:

```
Intent batteryIntent = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,
                    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
int rawlevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
double scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
double level = -1;
if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
    level = rawlevel / scale;
}
```

It can use a null BroadcastReceiver because of the sticky nature of the broadcast.

It uses the getApplicationContext() trick in case you are in a intent receiver and get the exception:

> android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException:
>   IntentReceiver components are not
>   allowed to register to receive
>   intents

Comment: Under certain situations (like running in a system service), getApplicationContext() will return null.  In that case the call should be: 
  context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

Comment: @hemisphire wrote "Under certain situations (like running in a system service), getApplicationContext() will return null".  I don't think that's always true.  Perhaps it depends on the type of service.

Comment: Perfect! I can do it without service now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the only way to get access the battery info from within a BroadcastReceiver without getting a ReceiverCallNotAllowedException.   Thanks for a useful tip! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
    public static String batteryLevel(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent  = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));   
        int    level   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int    scale   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
        int    percent = (level*100)/scale;
        return String.valueOf(percent) + "%";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Put this Code into your MainActivity

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        int level = i.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        pb.setProgress(level);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfield);
        tv.setText("Battery Level: " + Integer.toString(level) + "%");
    }

};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}
```

Comment: may i need to unresgiter this reciever as well in onPause i m unregistering but this is creating error 01-11 15:08:21.711: E/AndroidRuntime(31730): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.batterylevel.ChargeActivity$1@426304a0

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to get the battery level without receiving updates.

```
public float getMyBatteryLevel() {
        Intent batteryIntent = this.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        return batteryIntent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware, that the intent you get from registerReceiver call

```
Intent intent  = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

can be null. So please make a check before using the intent, e.g.

```
if(intent != null){ 
// do your stuff here... 
}
```

I just got a null pointer exception, causing the app to crash!