# android-Way of detecting low battery notification

Tags: android, notifications, battery

Is there a way to detect a low battery notification in android eclipse?I have an action game that needs to be paused when it appears.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tutorial in the official developers web about monitoring the battery level and charging state. I hope it helps you.

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

This post might be help full look at that [Battery Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661464/get-battery-level-before-broadcast-receiver-responds-for-intent-action-battery-c) Also look into this link [Battery Level and State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)