# How to tell if android popup notification is opened

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, notifications

I'm developing a unity game for android and I'm looking for a way to pause the game whenever a notification pops up on the screen.

This is troublesome because pause menu button is at the top of screen and therefore lies behind the popup message and player cannot click on it.

I already implemented OnApplicationFocus() and successfully pause the game. However I also want to pause in these kind of occasions.

[image]

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11361632/366064) for monitoring battery level but I'm looking for a general way for recognizing all kinds of popups.