# Android BatteryManager Returns only 1

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery, repeatingalarm

I am attempting to read the state of the Android battery when my repeating alarm broadcaster is called I have the following setup:

```
public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override       
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

            // Acquire the make of the device
            final String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
            final String AndroidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

            // Grab the battery information
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            final float batteryPct = level / (float)scale; 
    }

}
```

But I don't understand why it is returning that `batteryPct = 1`. Is there something I am missing here? I added the correct permissions based on the android Google page, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting `-1` for both `level` and `scale`. 
That is because you might be trying to broadcast `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` in the manifest.

`ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a sticky intent and you cannot register a receiver to it in the manifest. Try the following

```
 Intent i = new ContextWrapper(applicationContext).registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
 // now you can get the level and scale from this intent variable
int level = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float battPct = level/(float)scale;
```

You would not neet to device a receiver for this intent, just use the above mentioned way, whereever you want to use it.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! I had to make some minor changes to the Intent i line, due to it causing an error ("components are not allowed to register to receive intents"). But all good now.

Comment: Thank you for this piece of code. Just wasted 2-3 hours to find, why I get no information about battery on broadcast receiver, which declared on manifest.

Answer (score 2):

You might be getting -1 for both `level` and `scale` variable (the default value you specified), so try to print their values to make sure that the `intent` has those values set properly.

You should listen to `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` to [get battery level in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661464/get-battery-level-before-broadcast-receiver-responds-for-intent-action-battery-c)