# how to show to battery status on text view?

Tags: android, performance

Actually i am trying to make an android app to display a text when the battery becomes 50% ,m using text view to display the msg,but while loading the app it gets unfortunately stops.

here is my code:

Java file.

```
package com.example.abhi.batteryalarm;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Battery_Alarm extends ActionBarActivity {
    Intent batteryStatus;
    TextView txtView;
    String hello;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_battery__alarm);
        txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        hello="This is my first project";

        int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        if (level==50)
        {
            txtView.setText(hello);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_battery__alarm, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}

activity file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Battery_Alarm">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="62sp"
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="125dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What things i need to do?

Comment: Using broadcast receiver you get the current status.

Comment: Whats the exception. Paste the logs

Comment: where did you get this code? post logcat always when u have error, i thuink `batteryStatus` is not assigned so it's null, that's he problem,

Comment: its not showing error while running but when i run that app on my phone it says "Unfortunately,Battery Alarm has stopped", how to use broadcast receiver?plase help

Answer (score 1):

Add this,

```
batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

before,

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

and it will work.

Comment: now in place of displaying text i want to play a sound how i will proceed? i got this code:MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start(); but could't understand! please help

Comment: so you are saying that the music is not playing??? cause the code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the line which is causing the error :

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

It's because the batteryStatus intent is never initialized and is hence null.

Check out this answer about fetching the battery level : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047790/1239966

Answer (score 0):

You need to register batteryStatus.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

Comment: thanks!!!! its working now!,,,now suppose i want to run this application in background   so that when battery becomes 50% the app will open and display the text!!! is it possible to do???/