# registering receiver to filter that can not be found

Tags: android, android-intent

Can u help me find out why the registration of broadcast receiver returns null?
this is the code:

```
ScoIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
                sReceiver = new ScoReceiver(context, Tmp); 
                if (context.registerReceiver(sReceiver, ScoIntent) == null) {
                    Log("FBR.GetBlueConnect:Error", "Can not find receiver ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED");
                    HFS.DisplayText("Can not connect to Bluetooth Headset, Please Exit", true);
                }
```

and this is the reciver:

```
class ScoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {      
    public ScoReceiver(Context mcontext, Tools t){
    bContext = mcontext;
    tools = t;
}
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) { 
    tools.Log("ScoReceiver:onReceive", "In");

    //arg1 = new Intent(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED); 
    String action = arg1.getAction();
    tools.Log("ScoReceiver:onReceive", ">>> Bluetooth SCO state changed !!! ");
    if(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
        int status = arg1.getIntExtra(BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_STATE, AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_ERROR );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The javadocs say,

> Returns the first sticky intent found that matches filter, or null if
> there are none.

Does this receiver have a sticky intent? Here's a post that talks about the difference between a stick and non-sticky intent,

> [what is the difference between sendStickyBroadcast and sendBroadcast in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584497/what-is-the-difference-between-sendstickybroadcast-and-sendbroadcast-in-android)

Comment: I have read this java doc but on the ather hand this [link]|(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html) is about brodcast intents not sticky which wre mentioned dierctly in ather functions

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html in this :ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: please read about sticky intents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490913/what-is-a-sticky-intent-android