# Broadcast receiver is triggered automatically on start

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a registered `BroadcastReceiver` in my main activity. Activity sends a sticky in one of the tabs to trigger the broadcast receiver (`TabActivity` application).

Everything works fine, but when I restart the app the sticky is sent automatically (not triggered by user) and view is opened.

My question is: how is that possible? Did I misunderstand something? And how can I fix that?

MainActivity:
OnCreate:

```
    registerReceiver(openOutgoingCall, new IntentFilter("OPENOUTGOINGCALL"));
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver openOutgoingCall = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if(extras.isEmpty() == false) {
                HashMap<String,String> callData = (HashMap<String, String>) extras.get("callData");
                openOutgoingCall(callData); 
            }

        }
    };
```

Activity inside TabHost

```
public void openCall(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent("OPENOUTGOINGCALL");
    i.putExtra("callData", detailInfo);
    sendStickyBroadcast(i);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sticky broadcasts are supposed to stay around (even they are received)  so that they can be retrieved afterwards too. Perhaps you should try the simple way of broadcasting using:

```
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2584729/966550).