# How can I remove a sticky broadcast from memory?

Tags: java, android, broadcast

I'm sending a sticky broadcast from my service, and I receive it in one of my activities. I use the following code to send the broadcast:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("presence");
i.putExtra("name",xmlContactName);
i.putExtra("fullname", xmlContactName.split("@")[0]);
i.putExtra("presence", presence);

sendStickyBroadcast(i);
```

I use this code to receive the broadcast in my activity:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("presence")){
      Contact c = new Contact();
      Bundle contact = intent.getExtras();
      c.name = contact.getString("name");
      c.fullName = contact.getString("fullname");
      c.presence = contact.getString("presence");

      removeStickyBroadcast(intent);
    }
  };
}
```

According to several posts I found this is all I need to do, and as far as I know this intent is not sent to the activity again while my app is still running. However, when I close the app and run it again, I get the broadcast in my activity even without sending it from my service. It seems as though the broadcast is still lingering somewhere and it is received again after restarting the app. So far, the only thing I found to get rid of it is to restart the phone. I also unregister the receiver in my activity's onDestroy().
Do I have to do anything to completely remove the broadcast, or is it something I have to learn to live with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky broadcasts stick around even after your app is gone. The only reliable way to get rid of them is through phone restart. You can't manually make it go away yourself. This is the intended behavior of a sticky broadcast. It should stick around so that any app that registers itself to receive this broadcast should receive the latest cached version of the broadcast even if the originating app is dead and gone. If you want something that doesn't have this behavior then just use a regular broadcast.

Further reading:

- [Mark Murphy's explanation of sticky broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584497/what-is-the-difference-between-sendstickybroadcast-and-sendbroadcast-in-android)
- [Sticky broadcasts perils](http://porcupineprogrammer.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-sticky-broadcast-perils.html)

Comment: But if i use a regular broadcast, it does not arrive when my activity wasn't active at the time of sending. I have a contact list, and if it is not active it should still receive the broadcast when it does get active. Can this be done using a regular broadcast?

Comment: If that's the requirement, consider using a local db instead. Write your date to the local db in your service. Every time the activity becomes active, check if the local db has new data and retrieve it if it does. This will satisfy your requirement and also provide greater security since only your app can access your local db unlike a broadcast which any app can access.

Comment: Thank for the tip, this indeed seems like a better solution.